# Bijection between classes of natural transformations involving Kan extensions.

Tags: category-theory

I am reading the chapter on Kan extenions in the *Handbook of Categorical Algebra* by Francis Borceux and I am a bit confused about some of the steps he takes.

My main question is a step in his proposition 3.7.4:

> Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ be categories, with $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ small. Let $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ and $G:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ such that $\operatorname{Lan}_F{G}$ exists. Let $L:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ be the left adjoint of a functor $R:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$. Then $$\textbf{Nat}(\operatorname{Lan}_FG,RH)\cong\textbf{Nat}(G,RHF)$$

$\operatorname{Lan}_FG$ denotes the left Kan extension of $G$ along $F$. I have no clue why this should hold. At first I thought that for $\alpha\in \textbf{Nat}(\operatorname{Lan}_FG,RH)$, you would take $\alpha F$, the natural transformation which acts on objects as $(\alpha F)_A = \alpha_{F(A)}$ and then compose with the natural transformation  $G\Rightarrow \operatorname{Lan}_FG\circ F$given by the Kan extension. But going from $\alpha$ to $\alpha F$ does not give a bijection, since for example $F$ is not necessarily surjective on the objects. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the left Kan extension used in Borceux's book is

> Consider two functors $F : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ and $G : \mathcal A \to \mathcal C$. The left Kan extension, if it exists, is a pair $(K, \alpha)$ where
>
> - $K : \mathcal B \to \mathcal C$ is a functor,
> - $\alpha : G \Rightarrow K \circ F$ is a natural transformation,

> satisfying the following universal property: if $(H, \beta)$ is another pair with
>
> - $H : \mathcal B \to \mathcal C$ a functor,
> - $\beta : G \Rightarrow H \circ F$ a natural transformation,

> there exists a unique natural transformation $\gamma : K \Rightarrow H$ satisfying the equality $(\gamma * F) \circ \alpha = \beta$.

It's a useful skill to be able to convert between the presentation of something as a universal property and as saying that a certain functor is representable. Often this second presentation manifests as an isomorphism between two homsets, or in this case, two sets of natural transformations.

There's a map from $\textbf{Nat}(K, H)$ to $\textbf{Nat}(G, H \circ F)$ given by $\gamma \mapsto (\gamma * F) \circ \alpha$. By the universal property, this is an isomorphism. For any $\beta$ in $\textbf{Nat}(G, H \circ F)$, there's a unique $\gamma$ in $\textbf{Nat}(K, H)$ that maps to it.

Polishing up the notation, we have that for any functors $F : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$, $G : \mathcal A \to \mathcal C$ and $H : \mathcal B \to \mathcal C$, if $\operatorname{Lan}_F G$ exists, then $\textbf{Nat}(\operatorname{Lan}_F G, H) \cong \textbf{Nat}(G, H F)$. (Note that $\operatorname{Lan}_F G$ is the $K$ from above).

So in particular, with $R H$ as $H$, we get $\textbf{Nat}(\operatorname{Lan}_F G, R H) \cong \textbf{Nat}(G, R H F)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solved my problem. Thinking a bit further on what you said however, I can clearly see how the universal property implies a bijection betwoon those natural transformations, but I feel like the other way around isn't necessarily true. Would the second presentation just say, that if $(H,\beta)$ is another pair that these sets of natural transformations are bijective? Or is this a bit too weak? What exactly would the representable functor be in this case?

Comment: The representable functor would be $\textbf{Nat}(G, _ \circ F)$. Saying that it's representable says that there exists a functor $K$ and a natural isomorphism $\textbf{Nat}(K, _) \cong $\textbf{Nat}(G, _ \circ F)$.

Comment: There are two ways to say that a functor is representable, depending on whether the representing object has been chosen. You can say that a functor "is represtable", meaning that there exists an object and a natural isomorphism. You can also have an object $c$ and an element $r \in F(c)$ and say that "$(c, r)$ represents $F$" by saying that for any $(c', x)$, with $x \in F(c')$, there exists a unique morphism $f : c \to c'$ such that $F(f)(r) = x$. Note that you can't *just* choose $c$. You have to choose $r$ at the same time, otherwise you'll get something not quite the same.

Comment: So given a functor $K$, the mere existence of an isomorphism $\textbf{Nat}(K, \_) \cong \textbf{Nat}(G, \_ \circ F)$ might not be enough to uniquely specify the other necessary part: the natural transformation $\alpha : G \Rightarrow K \circ F$. A different isomorphism will give a different $\alpha$ (in general).

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me edit that first comment. Should be $\textbf{Nat}(G, \_ \circ F)$ and $\textbf{Nat}(K, \_) \cong \textbf{Nat}(G, \_ \circ F)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear :)